# SQL Query Help - Selecting between startdate and enddate

Tags: sql

Need help with three sql query's.

Our database holds the following information - Samples given

```
unique id -- package            -- startdate  -- enddate
1         -- Holiday Package 1  -- 05-08-2012 -- 05-25-2012
2         -- Holiday Package 2  -- 05-13-2012 -- 06-26-2012
3         -- Holiday Package 3  -- 05-14-2012 -- 05-14-2012
4         -- Holiday Package 4  -- 05-15-2012 -- 05-16-2012
5         -- Holiday Package 5  -- 05-21-2012 -- 07-16-2012
```

Query 1 - given today's date(05-11-2012) return all packages that lie within the next seven days

So for example if the date is 05-11-2012 i'd want the query to return all packages that are currently running for the next 7 seven days. So in the example this would be everything except Holiday Package 5.

Query 2 - Given today's date return all packages that lie within 14 days but not seven days

Result - Package 5 Only

Query 3 - Given today's date return all packages that lie within both 7 and 14 days but not either/or

Result - None

Thanks for any help.

Comment: which database you are using sql server/mysql/oracle..?

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes seemingly complex questions can have very simple answers. Try the following:

1)

```
SELECT *
FROM PackageTbl
WHERE :MyDate BETWEEN StartDate-7 AND EndDate
```

2)

```
SELECT *
FROM PackageTbl
WHERE :MyDate BETWEEN StartDate-14 AND StartDate-8
```

3) I didn’t quite understand your expected result for this query, the following query should return Package 1 and 2 (the AND part might not be required, just a precaution that some database servers may require):

```
SELECT *
FROM PackageTbl
WHERE :MyDate BETWEEN StartDate-7 AND EndDate-14
  AND EndDate >= StartDate+7
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
startdate > "given_date" and enddate < "given_date" + 7

startdate > "given_date" + 7 and enddate < "given_date" + 14

Combination of both the above conditions using "and"
```

Answer (score 0):

Query 1 -

```
declare @dte date='05-11-2012';
select * from Holiday_Package
where startdate <=  DATEADD(d,7,@dte)  
and enddate >= @dte
```

Query 2 -

```
declare @dte date='05-11-2012';
select * from Holiday_Package
where startdate between DATEADD(d,7,@dte) and DATEADD(d,14,@dte)
and enddate >= @dte
```

Query 3 -

```
declare @dte date='05-11-2012';
select * from Holiday_Package
where startdate between DATEADD(d,7,@dte) and DATEADD(d,14,@dte)
and enddate between DATEADD(d,7,@dte) and DATEADD(d,14,@dte)
```